# How to center the content of month input field?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering the text inside a HTML month-input field. Here's a simplified version of my HTML/CSS to demonstrate the issue:

If you run it, you'll see that it is not centered - and if you try "text-align: right", it doesn't move all the way right either. It does move with both alternatives, which is strange.

Any idea why this happens?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .monthSelector{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 250px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input disabled type="month" class="monthSelector" min="2017-01" max="2099-12" value="2018-01">

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is how it looks to me: As you can see the text is not centered inside the input box.

[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8aqLzg4x/ works fine here? I just copy pasted your code.

Comment: It is working fine with center right? any screenshot for expected output.

Comment: I'm using Opera and originally it's an electron app (same problem on both platforms). I have print screened what I see when I view the link you provided. I'm suspecting the problem might be related to me displaying the month input in Swedish? If you look closely at the picture it isn't centered.

Comment: @DanielSlätt, do you want to align input box text vertically center?

Comment: That's what I want :) (P.S - just realized I forgot to specify that it's the text I'm having trouble with - sorry!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work as expected because of the way `input type="month"` is rendered.

If you remove the disabled attribute you will see that (depending on  the browser) you have some arrows and carets on the right. Taking them into account your text is in dead center.

[image]

You need to add this CSS

```
input[type=month]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator, 
input[type=month]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

et voila

[image]

EDIT:

You can use `:disabled` CSS selector so it doesn't affect your other inputs

```
input[type=date]:disabled::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
input[type=date]:disabled::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @DanielSlätt See the edit if you would like to use this only on disabled inputs

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by default input controls being present (but invisible due to the input being disabled) when you give it `month` type. The inputs text is centered relatively to the inputs width minus the width of the controls. One way around it is giving them a manually selected `margin` to visually center the text.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .monthSelector{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 250px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: -15px; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input disabled type="month" class="monthSelector" min="2017-01" max="2099-12" value="2018-01">

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Daut has given a good explanation about the rendering of hidden elements in the `month` input.

You could go with the solution but it adds another challenge. Now, you are forced to make sure that the CSS has enough properties to render correctly in all browsers. Then you usually go for polyfills or you could just mark the input type as `text`.

Comment: If I were to have to concern about browsers then yes, I probably wouldn't keep it this way. But it's for an electron app so it's fine :)

Comment: Oh, yeah. Missed that.

Comment: The reason I have a disabled month selector is I have programmed two buttons to slide it right or left

Comment: Haha, that's no worries, I never clarified :) Your input could still be relevant for other people with similar issues.

Comment: Cool. I deleted my comment after getting it. Makes sense now.